# Typescript migration issue with react-dnd-html5-backend

Tags: javascript, typescript

My team is migrating Javascript project to Typescript and facing issue with 'react-dnd-html5-backend' & 'react-dnd' modules.

Modules are available in package file still i am getting build error.

enter image description here

Entire team blocked here & looking for suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Error details:

1) [image]

2)  ***TS2507: Type 'BackendFactory' is not a constructor function type.***

Comment: Are you sure the  `react-dnd-html5-backend` is compatible with typescript ? If it's a Javascript library, you might have to create it's type yourself.